# Filter the file from maven metadata plugin to deployment

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, nexus

I used maven metadata plugin to list my nexus artifacts in jenkins. It shown as below.

[image: maven-metadata]

Now, I want to select the version from jenkins shell to publish to deployment server. How can I do this? Can I access metadata plugin parameters using shell commands?

Answer (score 0):

Below command helped me to solve this.

```
#!/bin/bash

#get the selected snapshot artifact
selectSnap(){

    wget "$Select_Snapshot_Version_ARTIFACT_URL"
}

#get the selected release artifact
selectRel(){

    wget "$Select_Release_Version_ARTIFACT_URL"
}



selectSnap
selectRel
```

When I run this it will automatically save selected version into my jenkins workspace.